# What does "AVbad_allocstd" means in a call stack of a crash dump debugged with WinDbg?

Tags: c++, exception, crash, windbg, dump

I opened a crash dump file (.dmp) with both **Visual Studio** and **WinDbg**.

VS shows this line in the output:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x12345678 (ucrtbase.dll) in myapp.exe.1234.dmp: Fatal program exit requested.
```

and the last entry in the call stack points to:

```
__scrt_unhandled_exception_filter
```

When I open the same dump with WinDbg and I enter the command **kd** i get the call stack and some entries like this:

```
12345678  01234567 myapp!_TI2?AVbad_allocstd
```

Can I conclude that a `std::bad_alloc` exception occurred and caused a crash ?

Comment: Technically I'd say it is not the exception but the missing `catch` which directly caused the crash, but that's somewhat nitpicking. There's generally little you can do when `std::bad_alloc` happens. Prevention can be more useful, e.g. parameter validation. If somebody announces a 100 GB HTTP POST to your webserver, don't call `std::vector::reserve`.

Comment: @MSalters I'm wondering why the exception type is not visible in __VS__. Does __WinDbg__ make a guess or can I take it for granted ?

Comment: WinDBg doesn't make guesses; it shows symbol names. `myapp!_TI2?AVbad_allocstd` is a C++ mangled name. If I had to guess what it means, the `_T` might be related to the vtable of `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: To me this looks like your app has an unhandled exception handler and that one couldn't handle the exception because it couldn't allocate memory to do whatever it wants to do. Disabling the unhandled exception handler and letting WER generate a crash dump could help.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Ok but even if I disable the unhandled exception handler (this probably requires to shut down the whole C++ exception handling) the result would be always the same. If the process cannot allocate further memory it would crash anyway.

Comment: That's true, but you don't want the callstack to be inside the unhandled exception handler. You want to know where it really crashes.